# Pipe output from shell command to a python script that also uses commandline arguments

Tags: python, pipe, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pipe information from one command through a python script and change the output dynamically using command line arguments.

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | FindAndHighlight.py -f "icmp"
```

I'm able to grab stdin input and search for icmp if I hard code it but I'm unable to figure out how to pass command line arguments to the script and receive piped data at the same time.

The core of my code is as follows. Thanks for any help!

```
def main(argv): 
    global debug, searchfor
    try:                                
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h f:d", ["help", "debug", "find"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print
        print
        print hilite("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", 'hi-red', True)
        print hilite("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!### Bad Switch! ###!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", 'hi-red', True)
        print hilite("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", 'hi-red', True)
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-d", "--debug"):
            debug = True
        elif opt in ("--f", "--find"):
            searchfor = arg


    source = "".join(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])

print "Search String is: ", searchfor

# searchfor = "icmp" ## If I was to hard code the search string I would un-comment this line

try:
    buff = ''

    while True:
        buff += sys.stdin.read(1)

        if buff.endswith('\n'):
            if searchfor and searchfor in buff:
                buff = buff.replace(searchfor, hilite(searchfor, 'red', False))

            print buff[:-1]
            buff = ''

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    pass
```

Comment: `--f` should be `-f`. Other than that, it seems like it should work if you add all the necessary `import` statements.

Comment: Oh right silly me! Sorry guys the code above does work once I removed the double dash from the switch. Thanks Barmar!